# Databinding ASP.Net repeater from Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, data-binding

I've got some Ajax code with calls a `WebMethod` from within my back-end code and now want to be able to databind the information it receives to a repeater.

Here's my Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "default.aspx/Call_Car",
  data: '{ Ref: "MD12355"}',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    var cars = msg.d;
    $.each(cars, function(index, car) {
        $('.test').text(car.PICKUP);
        $('.test2').text(car.SUPPLIER); 
    });
  }

});
```

At the moment it is writing the fields `PICKUP` and `SUPPLIER` to my labels but ideally i want it to be able to databind my repeater with all the data.

Here's the response I get back from this call

```
{"d":[{"SUPPLIER":"Magos Car Hire","PICKUP":"Funchal Airport"}]}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, a repeater binds on the server side, and you are returning client side data.

You can use one of the jQuery grids or a variety of other grids (kendoui im particularly fond of from telerik)

Or you could request the page from the server that contains the data and grid and load that via ajax.

This is addressed in a bit more detail here:
[Bind Data to Repeater using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703145/bind-data-to-repeater-using-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the problem with jQuery grids is that i'm unable to format them in the particular way i'm trying like this in a repeater `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SUPPLIER") %>` - I'm trying to have the flexibility of Repeater

Comment: can you give more details on how you are trying to formaT? it looks like like SUPPLIER is plain text

Comment: I've actually had to scrap the ajax call for this particular case as it was overcomplicating everything and i've just databound my repeater server-side instead - Thanks for the help tho i've started using jQGrid for some other bits i'm using :)